# get deleted branch names in GitHub

Tags: git, github, command-line

I have this situation: We have a project at GitHub.com and someone makes a branch, changes something and makes a pull request at GitHub.com. The owner of this project approves this change, merges it into master (or another branch) and deletes then the branch on GitHub.com.

So, when I go to the pull request I can still see the name of the branch even if the project owner deleted it.

Is it possible to get this branch in the command line somehow ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [GitHub API](https://developer.github.com/v3/pulls/#list-pull-requests):

```sh
GET /repos/:owner/:repo/pulls
```

For example:

```sh
GITHUB_API_HEADER="Accept: application/vnd.github.v3+json"
GITHUB_API_URI="https://api.github.com"
TOKEN=<your_token>
OWNER=<owner>
REPO=<repo>

body=$(curl -sSL -H "Authorization: token $TOKEN" -H "$GITHUB_API_HEADER" "$GITHUB_API_URI/repos/$OWNER/$REPO/pulls")

echo "$body"
```

You can of course use `jq` or any other tool to extract whatever you want from the result, and get exactly the closed source branches.

For creating a personal access token, follow the [GitHub Docs](https://docs.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/creating-a-personal-access-token).